# Reset password problems in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I executed the `php artisan make:auth` command a couple of days ago and now out of nowhere if I reset password and insert a password with below minimum chars no errors show and the view is intact as original.

Any guesses?

Comment: did you change in any code ? `reset password and insert a password` what do you mean by `insert a password` ?

Comment: unable to understand your problem.

Comment: As I am doing the reset password I have to insert the new password and confirmation. When I submit the form and the password is wrong (not well formated or not min length) the page only refreshs and shows no errors. And I haven't made any changes to the code